# No output from print statements in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have compiled a program to execute sequentially (not parallel) in fortran 90. I am trying to debug the program with print statements to check my rusty `gdb` fu. I am compiling the files with `gfortran -c -O2 -ffast-math -ggdb`. However, none of these statements print anything:

```
print *, variablename1, variablename2
write(6,*) variablename1, variablename2
write(*,*) variablename1, variablename2
```

The compiled program prints nothing and executes as if the statements are not there. Could I be missing something simple and obvious?

Comment: All of those should produce output.  How are you running the executable?  In a terminal window?  Probably the problem is in a aspect for which you haven't provided information here.  I suggest trying a smaller test example.

Comment: You are right, with simpler programs this works... could there be anything that would cause it to not print?

Comment: What do you expect to see?   Are your variables holding empty strings?  Try write to a non-preconnected unit and see if the fort.nn file is opened.   What about buffering?   Does your program crash before the buffers are flushed?   Use a fflush() call.

Comment: Instead of the call to flush() you can also set the environment variable [GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GFORTRAN_005fUNBUFFERED_005fALL.html).

Comment: Thank you! These are helpful leads. Yes -- in this case they should be `integer` variables which have been initialized so should be `.gt.0`, but I will look into these issues.

Comment: @Andrej, I did not try the flush call but will also keep in mind for next time. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!  Damn, I should have written an answer instead of a comment ;-)

Comment: @alexurba, please do! And I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks, but it's okay.  Andrej suggested virtually the same.  And anyway it was more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments it turned out that there was a problem with buffering of the output stream. This can be controled by calling the `flush` statement, the non-standard `flush()` intrinsic subroutine or by compiler-specific environment variables like [`GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GFORTRAN_005fUNBUFFERED_005fALL.html).